# DB2 how to send an email from Stored Procedure?

Tags: email, stored-procedures, db2

I have a scenario where I need to send an email from my stored procedure in DB2.

However I have not been able to figure out any so far, apart from using Task Center or Query Patroller.

Can someone suggest me some pointers to this? I do not want to do it from any other language though. Thanks.

Comment: Our production database (Oracle) sends emails by opening a socket to port 25 and talking raw SMTP. It's hideous. Please don't do that.

Comment: If you're using DB2 why not contact their dedicated technical support directly?  
It seems like their Smart Answer system - which to my understanding is essentially a stackoverflow for DB2, would be a better way to get a quicker answer in this case.

Answer (score 3):

With 9.7, you can use the UTL_MAIL or UTL_SMTP built-in packages.

Comment: However, this is not supported in Express-C edition: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053670.html :(

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in in DB2 to do that, like xp_sendmail in SQL Server.

You have to write your stored procedure in one of the hosted languages (Java, C++) and then use an API from that language to send the mail.

See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205bhogal/0205bhogal.html) on how to do it using Java.